# I am not able to cut and paste a text file from /home to /home/Desktop folder in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I am NOT able to cut and paste a text file from /home to /home/Desktop folder in Ubuntu 20.04 ... The error shown in the popup is : **There was an error moving the file into /home/aakash/Dekstop. Can't copy over directory.**

What does this mean ?

[image: See the attached screenshot]

Comment: @GopalS Your suggestion is about a different issue. In your suggestion, it was tried to copy ./Desktop . But in my case, I am trying to cut and paste a text file using mouse' right click Cut and Paste option. There is no role of terminal and command line instructions in my case.

Comment: You already have a directory named `rough`. You can't paste a file named `rough` in to Desktop while the directory exists

Comment: The filename has to be unique. There is already a folder (directory) named `rough`. Try renaming the text file first to `rough.txt` and then move it to the desktop.

Comment: @muru Oh Thanks a lot. I am surprised because this was not a problem in Windows. In Windows, a file and folder name can be same.

Comment: @AakashKumar no, they can't.

Comment: @muru yes they can. I have tested it. The folder and the filename can be exactly same.

Comment: @AakashKumar I don't know what you're talking about, but some path like `C:\Documents\foo` cannot both be a file and a directory at the same time. It's the same thing here.

Comment: @muru I am saying that: In Windows, suppose we make a folder named "A" in the path D:\ where D is just a drive. Now, let us open the D drive using mouse click and then create a text file using Mouse-right-click -> "New text document" option and name it just "A". The result will be that now the D drive (D:\) has a folder "A" as well as a text file named "A".

Comment: @AakashKumar yeah, you're missing the "hidden" extension of the file (`.txt` probably). The file isn't just `A`, it's `A.txt`.

Comment: @muru Ok, then it might be that each and every file in Windows have a hidden extension. And that's why they do not collide with folder name

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/494323/334516

Comment: @muru There it is. Thanks muru so much. Now the things are crystal clear.

Comment: @muru Could you please help me with 1 last thing ? How did "@To Do" edited the question so that the image is now visible embedded in the webpage (instead of a link to the image earlier) ?? Is it because of he has points because of which he was allowed to upload the image may be ??

Comment: Yes, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498/270345

Comment: @muru Thank you again!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a folder named exactly like the file you're attempting to move. You cannot have a file and a folder with the same name in the same parent folder.

Rename the file or the folder and you will be able to move the file to the Desktop.

Comment: Oh Thanks a lot. I am surprised because this was not a problem in Windows. In Windows, a file and folder name can be same.

Comment: Hey, how did you edit the question to show the image ?? I am curious to know. Is that because you may have more points in your account which permitted you to do so ??